# search for pattern x (and print that line), in subsequent lines grep lines with patten y untill the next empty line

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

Example text:

---

```
dn: uid=test,ou=domain.eu,o=org
uid: test
mailEquivalentAddress: john@domain.eu
mailEquivalentAddress: johndoe@domain.eu

dn: uid=test2,ou=domain.eu,o=org
uid: test2

dn: uid=test3,ou=domain.eu,o=org
uid: test3
```

---

So not all entries have a mailEquivalentAddress, more than one mailEquivalentAddress is possible.

I want to get all entries that have one or more mailEquivalentAddresses.
To explain the title: grep for all lines that start with a dn: and all subsequent lines, but only if there is one or more mailEquivalentAddress, stop at the next empty line.

So the output I'm trying to get is:

```
dn: uid=test,ou=domain.eu,o=org
uid: test
mailEquivalentAddress: john@domain.eu
mailEquivalentAddress: johndoe@domain.eu
```

With a variable amount of mailEquivalentAddresses.

Comment: Where is sample code?

Answer (score 4):

I would use `awk` for that:

```
awk '$1 ~ /^dn:/{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~ /^mailEquivalentAddress:/){print; break}}}' RS='' file
```

- `RS=''` is a special value of the *record separator*. It tells awk to split the file into records by a blank line (paragraphs) and set's the field delimiter to newline.
- `$1 ~ /^dn:/` checks if the first line in a paragraph starts with `dn:`
- The program itself is a loop trough all fields which checks whether the field starts with the word `mailEquivalentAddress:`. If such a field is found `awk` will print the paragraph.

Comment: This script prints the record if the `mailEquivalentAddress` is not set, if the same occurs somewhere else `ie not as a key` and also for a record that contains only `mailEquivalentAddress`, ie `without any other keys`.

Comment: I don't see the requirement in the question that the `mailEquivalentAddress` must not be empty. Do you? Note that setting a config value to an empty string might be by intention. Furthermore where do you see the requirement that there must be other keys besides `mailEquivalentAddress` as well?

Comment: From `So not all entries have a mailEquivalentAddress` isn't it obvious that the key should be non-empty? The op might clarify this. `grep for all lines that start with a dn` makes clear that it should start with `dn`. I just made an edit to mine to deal with this. You may review it  if time permits

Comment: Please read my answer carefully. I've added the `dn:` restriction already. However, the input data looks as if this is guaranteed. The data is not something artificial, these are ldap records

Comment: Okay I see the point now. :) . By the way, it is the first time I am seeing the usage `RS=''`. I have used `-v RS=''` and  `BEGIN{RS=''}`.  Are all the same?

Comment: Yes, it is doing the same. They are so called *arguments*. Check this http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html

Comment: The ldap schema does not allow for an empty mailEquivalentAddress value. So "in theory" there should be no empty ones....from that perspective it would be ok if empty ones are displayed.

Comment: @HermanGreeven Ok, then I'll keep it as it is. I would also suggest to do so.

Answer (score 3):

**Sample text** in `file`

```
dn: uid=test,ou=domain.eu,o=org
uid: test
mailEquivalentAddress: john@domain.eu
mailEquivalentAddress: johndoe@domain.eu

dn: uid=test2,ou=domain.eu,o=org
uid: test2

dn: uid=test3,ou=domain.eu,o=org
uid: test3

dn: uid=test4,ou=domain.eu,o=org
uid: test4
mailEquivalentAddress: jason@bourne.eu
mailEquivalentAddress: matt@damon.eu
```

**Script**

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="";ORS="\n\n"}/^dn:.*\nuid:.*\nmailEquivalentAddress: [[:alnum:]]+/'  file
```

**Output**

```
dn: uid=test,ou=domain.eu,o=org
uid: test
mailEquivalentAddress: john@domain.eu
mailEquivalentAddress: johndoe@domain.eu

dn: uid=test4,ou=domain.eu,o=org
uid: test4
mailEquivalentAddress: jason@bourne.eu
mailEquivalentAddress: matt@damon.eu
```

**Notes:**

1. I assumed that `mailEquivalentAddress:` can be considered a key.
2. From the input you've given it is evident that you have a blank line between each record, So I have kept the record separator `RS=""`.
3. By `/^dn:.*\nuid:.*\nmailEquivalentAddress: [[:alnum:]]+/` we look the record

   - to check if the dn(at the start) and uid keys are mandatorily present in the record.
   - for a line that begins with `mailequivalentAddress:`, if yes we can be sure that it is a key. Then,we make sure it is non-empty by `[[:alnum:]]+`,if so,we print the record.

Comment: You are actually doing more or less what my answer suggests but less accurate since you only check if the term is *somewhere* in the paragraph but not if it is a *key* and without an explanation at all. Why do you post such an answer?

Comment: @hek2mgl : I think I have rectified the accuracy issue.

Comment: Have you tested it?

Comment: @hek2mgl Did so,  for instance it won't give a positive match for either `uid:mailEquivalentAddress:`  or for a record that contains only `mailEquivalentAddress:some@stuff`. Can't think of any other test cases though

Comment: Ok, that was my fault. You can even simplify the command. Edited that

Comment: @hek2mgl : Thanks for the edit. Also, I have changed `/\nmailEquivalentAddress:/` to `/\nmailEquivalentAddress: [[:alnum:]]+/` to prevent false positive in the case where there is an empty key. Checking the correctness of the mail address is out of scope for this question though..

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/^dn:/{:a;$!{N;/\n$/!ba};/mailEquivalentAddress:/p}' file
```

If a line begins `dn:` fetch more lines until an empty line or the end of file. The test those lines for the presence of `mailEquivalentAddress:` and if found print them.

Comment: This does the job indeed!! Tnx.

Comment: Good answer! Just one thing, it should be `/\nmailEquivalentAddress:/p` to ensure it is a key